# Eclipse won't open

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to run Eclipse on Ubuntu, but it is not working and I don't quite understand the log file. Here is what is said:

```
    !SESSION 2017-09-19 11:59:59.037 ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=debbuild java.version=9-internal java.vendor=Oracle
Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=pt_BR
Command-line arguments: -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.409 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
"org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1]" could not be
resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.417 !MESSAGE Bundle
initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar
was not resolved.

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.427 !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root
constraints are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
2017-09-19 12:00:04.428 !MESSAGE Bundle
initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar
was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2
0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.428 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.430 !MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.430 !MESSAGE Bundle
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1] was not
resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0
2017-09-19 12:00:04.430 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-19 12:00:04.431 !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini). at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native
Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629) at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584) at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a very old version of Java installed. The logs are saying it needs at least Java 1.4 but it can't be found.

Comment: @greg-449: It says `java.version=9` at the top of the log.

Comment: Which Eclipse version is this? Could you please try to run Eclipse with Java 8 instead of 9? Your Eclipse version may be incompatible with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse needs to jdk to run. You can install it with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```